# Inconsistent ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: io, machine-learning, theano, keras

I am trying to train a model using Keras and I am getting a "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file". The part that confuses me is that I get it at a different point along the training process each time, so I don't know what is causing it.

Here's my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

np.random.seed(1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=X_train.shape[1], output_dim=50, init='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(input_dim=50, output_dim=50, init='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(input_dim=50, output_dim=y_train_ohe.shape[1], init='uniform', activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-7, momentum=.9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(X_train, y_train_ohe, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=300, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

Each time it's different, but I get an output like this:

```
Train on 54000 samples, validate on 6000 samples
Epoch 1/50
54000/54000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.2964 - val_loss: 0.2558
Epoch 2/50
54000/54000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2927 - val_loss: 0.2546
Epoch 3/50
12000/54000 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2829

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-cdea496300a5> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train_ohe, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=300, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)

/home/julius/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.pyc in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    400                               shuffle=shuffle,
    401                               class_weight=class_weight,
--> 402                               sample_weight=sample_weight)
    403 
    404     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,
```

As you can see, the model trains through a few epochs before giving me this error. X_train and y_train are from the MNIST dataset. Also, I found that I turn verbose off, the problem goes away. This basically solves it, but doesn't let me use verbose. Is there any way I can get it to display the updates without getting this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34046749

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem with adding `%%capture` as the first line of the cell which contains `model.fit()`